# ReferenceError: $ is not defined for $.get

Tags: javascript, rest

I had a javascript function that worked perfectly until I changed the names of the variables in the database but I also changed the variable names in my Java classes and Facade.  Here is my javascript:

```
function getStud(responeType) {
    var status = 0;
    var theId = document.getElementById("studform").studid.value;
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/rt/services/students/"+theId;
    $.get(url, function(data, status){
      alert("DATA: "+data+"\nStatus: "+status);
      var output = document.getElementById("studout");

      if(status == "success"){
        if(responseType=="text"){alert("text"); output.innerHTML = data;}
        elseif(responseType=="json"){
          alert("json");
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           output.innerHTML = "Student Object:: Last: "+data.Lastname+" First: "+data.Firstname +" ("+data.ID+")";}
      else{
        output.innerHTML = "Sorry, an error occured: "+status;
      }
   },responeType);
}
```

previously when it worked the only difference was the data.retrievals, they were: data.lname, data.fname, data.id because in my SQL database the column names were fname, lname, id.  When I switched the database they changed to Firstname, Lastname, ID.  I also made sure the change my database properties in my Singleton class.  If you need any more code let me know.

I have included jquery in my HTML head as src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
with script tags around it.

UPDATE:
When I run the $.get()function in Firefox with the console in Firebug I can actually see the GET function going to the server and the code executes.  What would cause it to not execute in the script though?

Comment: Did you add jquery.js on your page?

Comment: Yes I added is as <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js:>

Comment: @BobbyStrickland Is it included before `getStud()` is used? Does `jQuery === $`? Any use of [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) or another library which defines its own `$` global (e.g. PrototypeJS)?

Comment: yeah it's included before the function, no use of jQuery.noConflict() or anything else.

Comment: In addition, elseif is not a keyword in javascript as far as I can tell.  You'll need a space between else and if in any occurrences of elseif in this code.
You may be thinking of python's "elif".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you've pasted this in, but your input param for getStud is misspelled.

function getStud(responeType)

should be

function getStud(responseType)

Comment: find and replace "responeType" with "responseType" as that error is there a few times in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the jQuery object $ isn't yet defined because you have not imported it into your current page. Try adding this line of code to your HTML at the end of your header tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have that included.